# jquery tokenize response showing [Object]

Tags: jquery, ajax, tokenize

I am developing email system for communication between teachers and students in school.I am using tokenize plugin from the [Zellerda tokenize](https://www.zellerda.com/projects/tokenize) for showing the names of students when teacher tries to type each letters of their corresponding students.It works fine.My issue is I need to check the response of tokenize event whether it is empty or not.

My response is in json.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../js/jquery_multipleSelect/jquery.tokenize.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery_multipleSelect/jquery.tokenize.js"></script>

 $('#to_message').tokenize({
    datas: "module/teachers/communication/view_student_search.php?action=new_message",
    dataType: "json",
    autosize: true,
    nbDropdownElements: 30,
    onAddToken: function(value, text, e){ 
        $( "#compose_message" ).append( '<input type="hidden" name="students_ids[]" id="'+value.split('_')[0]+'" value="'+value.split('_')[0]+'" >' );
        $( "#compose_message" ).append( '<input type="hidden" name="family_ids[]" id="'+value.split('_')[1]+'" value="'+value.split('_')[1]+'" >' ); 
    },
    onRemoveToken: function(value, e){
        $( "#"+value.split('_')[0] ).remove();
        $( "#"+value.split('_')[1] ).remove();  
    }
});

$('#to_message') 
        .ajaxStart(function() {
            $(document).find('#loading').show();    
        })
        .ajaxStop(function(e) {
           $(document).find('#loading').hide();
        })
       .ajaxComplete(function(e){
           alert(e);
        });
```

EDIT:I need to check whether the response is null or not.I get the json array as response.In console I can see the array is null sometimes.But I need to show a message when response is null.I have used ajaxComplete event and alerted the result,then also,its not working according to my need.Pls help me